# How to do * and a calculation in SELECT statement mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute the following mySQL query:

```
SELECT 
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date_identified, 
    IFNULL(date_closed, 
    CURDATE())) as days_open, 
    * 
FROM (`risks`) 
ORDER BY `WBS` ASC LIMIT 10
```

but I keep getting an error. However, if I remove `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `*` and instead do:

```
SELECT 
    id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date_identified, 
    IFNULL(date_closed, 
    CURDATE())) as days_open 
FROM (`risks`) 
ORDER BY `WBS` ASC LIMIT 10
```

Then the query executes successfully. Is there any way I can change this query to include `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `*`?

Comment: We,ll you could just type in the columns you want instead of using `*`.

Comment: Just add the table name? `risks`.*

Comment: @Zane No. Using a column list is dumb.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO What do you mean? People rarely need ALL the fields from a query. `SELECT *` is usually a sign of sloppy/lazy programming.

Comment: Remove the `,` after `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` so its just `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *,`

Comment: @MikeB Please show evidence to support your argument. I've worked with sequel for long time.

Comment: @MikeB You souldn't take FreshPrinceofSO seriously when he makes a comment like that (he doesn't really mean it, he's just messing around)

Comment: @Lamak I might be going on a limb here, but I think MikeB knows that.

Comment: apologies, sarcasm detector is on the fritz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think to make this work out is to include the row source name (or alias) before the `*`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date_identified, IFNULL(date_closed, CURDATE())) as days_open, 
    `risks`.* 
FROM 
    (`risks`) 
ORDER BY 
    `WBS` ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This only works if I remove the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. How can I include the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS?

Comment: @Paul I think I speak for everyone when I say. What?

Comment: I had to remove the comma after SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.

Answer (score 3):

`sql_calc_found_rows` is a directive, not a field, you don't put a comma after it:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND ROWS field1, field2, calc1, calc2, etc...
                          ^--- no comma
```

It's similar `INSERT IGNORE` - ignore is a directive, not a field.